# Why does the Canvas window not show up?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to java and have some problems. Recently i have been working on a project which works with `UnfoldingMap` and Processing Libraries.
I import the libraries into the project but every time I create a new package and class for setting up a new canvas,it says:

```
Usage: PApplet <appletname>
For additional options, see the Javadoc for PApplet

Process finished with exit code 1
```

...and the Canvas Window does not show up.
Each time I should go to Edit configuration... and create a new class in applet that should have the same name with the class that I created before for solving this.
How can I fix the problem?!

Comment: I think the question is really unclear, please consider rephrasing it.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jat9f.jpg) is the code that I talked about , when I run, the error appears,and from where I marked,should go to edit configuration ... .

Then add class to applet,as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGsdU.jpg).